# Is there a SQL function that restarts the row count every 3 rows?

Tags: sql, count, subset, partition, row-number

I would like to use a row counting function to count every three rows so that my output is similar to what is shown below. I have tried to use ROW_NUMBER, NTILE, and RANK, however I can not figure out a way to partition or subset into groups of 3. How can I generate a row count like what is shown below?

| Food | Row Count |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 |
| Banana | 2 |
| Pear | 3 |
| Grape | 1 |
| Orange | 2 |
| Avocado | 3 |

Comment: How are you sorting the rows? There seems to be no ordering.

Comment: Fair question - the table should be ordered alphabetically by Food. In retrospect, I would have displayed the table that way with same 1,2,3,1,2,3 pattern descending

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can use arithmetic -- assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering.  A typical method is:

```
select t.*
       row_number() over (order by <ordering col>) % 3 as row_count
from t;
```

Note that `%` is the modulo operator.  Some databases use `MOD()` as a function or infix operator for the same purpose.

Comment: @DestructionBringer00 This answer should be the accepted.